# Bug pandas when plotting dataframe with non-unique column names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I found unexpected behaviour when plotting a pandas dataframe with non unique column names. In particular, each column is plotted twice, causing (among other problems) the colors in the legend not to reflect the colors of lines plotted.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50, 2))
data.columns = ['a', 'a']
ax = data.plot()
```

[image]

As further confirmation that two lines are plotted:

```
ax.get_lines()
Out[8]: <a list of 4 Line2D objects>
```

I am using pandas 0.16.2  and matplolib 1.5.1.
I am aware that this issue is resolved in pandas 0.18, but I wonder it you can provide more details on why this is happening and if there is a fix.
Thanks